# Задача по рекурсии

Tags: php, рекурсия

Всем привет. Изучаю PHP
Столкнулся с интересной задачей, не могу решить ((

Дано натуральное число N. Выведите все его цифры по одной, в обратном порядке, разделяя их пробелами или новыми строками. При решении этой задачи нельзя использовать строки, массивы, циклы. Разрешена только рекурсия и целочисленная арифметика.

Например дано число: 5671, вывод должен быть - 1 7 6 5.

Подскажите пожалуйста )

Comment: Для меня в этой задачке самое сложное - это поставить пробел или перевод строки, т.к. использование строк запрещено. )) А в общем, всё элементарно. Деление по модулую + `(int)($current_number /10)`, пока последняя операция != false

Comment: Спасибо! Правда не совсем понял как деление по модулю здесь применить... Что то вроде $current_number = 5671
$current_number % $current_number

Прошу прощение если вопросы туповатые )) Только учусь )

Comment: `function foo($n){
 echo $n % 10;
 if($n = (int)($n / 10)) {
  foo($n);
 }
 
}
foo(5671);`

Comment: ААААА!!! Понял ))
Вот спасибо!!! Если придумаю как пробелы поставить напишу.

<?php
function foo($n)
 { 
 echo $n % 10; // делим по модулю
 if($n = (int) // пока $n целое число выполняем 
  ($n / 10)) 
  { 
  foo($n);  // тут рекурсия 
  } 
} 
foo(5671);

Для себя комменты оставил

Comment: echo $n % 10 . ' ';  - так пробел добавил

Comment: Всё пропало))) Это же использование строки!

Comment: В задаче описано также использование новой строки для разделения. Возможно "\r\n" пройдет, ведь это экранирующая последовательность. Еще вариант: echo chr(32);

Comment: ну да ))) точно ' ' - это уже строка ))
блин )))